# OS X natd, nat between en0 and tap0

Tags: macos, nat

I'm trying to connect a tap0 and en0 interface with the natd. The (simplified) background is:

I have one application running on a smartphone and a simple UDP Server running on my laptop. The UDP Server is listening on the tap-Interface and I want to speak to the server with my smartphone application. (As I said this is a bit simplified, the UDP Server has to listen on the tap Interface and cannot listen on en0.)

I tried the following:

- Open tap0:

  ```
  $ su
  $ exec 5<>/dev/tap0   (running in one terminal-tab)
  ```
- Set the tap0-address, netmask, etc.

  ```
  $ sudo ifconfig tap0 inet 10.1.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.1.1.255
  ```
- Enable Port forwarding

  ```
  $ sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
  ```
- Start natd:

  ```
  $ sudo /usr/sbin/natd -alias_address MY_EN0_IP \
      -interface tap0 -use_sockets -same_ports -dynamic -clamp_mss \
      -enable_natportmap -natportmap_interface en0 \
      -redirect_port udp 10.1.1.100:50000 50000 -l
  ```
- Start a sample UDPServer, listening on 10.1.1.100:50000

Netstat shows the opened port:

```
$ netstat -n | grep 50000
udp4       0      0  10.1.1.100.50000       *.*
```

When I send a packet from my smartphone to the laptop with target:MY_EN0_IP:50000 I can see the packet with Wireshark arriving at en0, but the laptop is answering with an "ICMP port unreachable" message.

I have no clue what is going wrong, shouldn't the natd open port 50000 on en0, accept the packets and NAT them to the tap0 interface? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like I have found the solution myself by using pf and pfctl. This seems to work:

- activate port forwarding:

  ```
  $ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```
- Add the following rule to the pf.conf (located in /private/etc/)

  "rdr on en0 proto udp from any to any port 50000 -> 10.1.1.100 port 50000" (without quotation marks and right below the "rdr-anchor"
- read pf rules:

  ```
  $ sudo pfctl -f /private/etc/pf.conf
  ```
- activate pf:

  ```
  $ sudo pfctl -e
  ```